# Do we have any catalog of Standard Salesforce fields by DisplayType with a checkbox if they are sortable?

Tags: displaytype

When we build a managed package for a client with custom functionality which is supposed to be working for any type of the field, it is quite easy to create some custom field to match some DisplayType which correspond to one of the field types which are available for custom field creation. However, if we need to check if some DisplayType works, which doesn't correspond to any of the field types which are available for custom field creation, it is a big challenge to find any standard field which has given DisplayType.

Do we have anywhere any catalog of Standard Salesforce fields by DisplayType with information if they are sortable?

Answer (score -1):

I created a catalog of standard fields available at the current release https://gist.github.com/bdovh/5608ab7711ac73b51ac54cfe329f98dc

Using the code https://gist.github.com/bdovh/00cb9eefa07578a7561d1746c0085a37

```
Set<Schema.DisplayType> displayTypes = new Set<Schema.DisplayType>();

Map<String,SObjectType> stuff = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Map<DisplayType, List<String>> fieldsByType = new Map<DisplayType, List<String>>();
for (SObjectType theType : stuff.values()) {
    Map<String, SObjectField> theFields = theType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    
    for (SObjectField theField : theFields.values()) {
        displayTypes.add(theField.getDescribe().getType());
                                DisplayType type = theField.getDescribe().getType();
                                
                                if (fieldsByType.get(type) == null) {
                                                fieldsByType.put(type, new List<String>());
                                }
                                List<String> fields = fieldsByType.get(type);
                                fields
                                                .add( 
                                                theType.getDescribe().name + '.' + 
                                                theField.getDescribe().name + 
                                                (theField.getDescribe().isSortable() ? ' !sortable':''));
                                fieldsByType.put(type, fields);
    }
}
for (DisplayType t: fieldsByType.keySet()) {
                System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ type: ' + t);
    String value = String.join(fieldsByType.get(t), '\n');
                System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ value: ' + value);
                while (value.length() > 131072) {
                                insert new ErrorLog__c(Name = '' + t, Line__c = value.left(131072));
                                value = value.right(value.length() - 131072);
                }
                insert new ErrorLog__c(Name = '' + t, Line__c = value);
}
```